# Read a formatted date in Python 2.3?

Tags: python, datetime

I had never worked with the datetime module in Python 2.3, and I have a very silly problem. I need to read a date in the format

```
'10-JUL-2010'
```

then subtract a day (I would use `timedelta`), and return the string

```
'09-JUL-2010 00:00:00 ET'
```

of course, this is for hundreds of dates. While it should be trivial, I cannot find the info on how to read formatted dates in Python 2.3! Help!

**Edit**

I am able to retrieve the formatted date as a tuple, but it will not accept the `timedelta` object for subtraction! Still working on it...

** Edit **

Finally... thanks to your help I was able to solve the problem as follows:

```
print (datetime(*(time.strptime(date_string, format)[0:6])).strftime('%d-%b-%Y')).upper()+'00:00:00 ET'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `datetime.datetime.strptime()`, but the documentation is awful for that function, it's effectively the reverse operation of `datetime.datetime.strftime()`.

The format string you're looking for is: `'%d-%b-%Y'`

See: http://www.python.org/doc/2.3.5/lib/node211.html and http://www.python.org/doc/2.3.5/lib/datetime-datetime.html *and* http://www.python.org/doc/2.3.5/lib/module-time.html

Edit: *Oh snap!* There is no strptime in the datetime module in python 2.3.  It's in the `time` module, you'll have to use that one instead.

Comment: Yes, but the `strptime()` function is not available!

Comment: It's in the time module, as noted in the edit.  That last link will show you the light.

Comment: Thanks... not I'm trying to get the result of `strptime()` to subtract a `timedelta` object. They're not compatible! this is a nightmare!

Comment: Thank you, Sufian, your help with the link from THC4k helped me solved the problem. I will be accepting yours as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is no builtin for that in 2.3, [only from 2.5 on](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime). But for that one format you can parse it by hand ...

```
months = { 'JAN' : 1, 'FEB' : 2, ... } # write that yourself :p
day,mon,year = thedate.split('-')
day = int(day)
mon = months[mon]
year = int(year)
parsed = datetime.datetime(day=day, month=month, year=year)
```

Answer (score 0):

If strptime() is not working out for you there is also the option of brute forcing it with a regex:

```
import re
import date
timestamp_regex = re.compile(r"(\d\d)-(\w\w\w)-(\d\d\d\d)")
# month_mapping: a mapping for 3 letter months to integers
d1 = datetime.date(int(match.group(3)),          #year
                   month_mapping[match.group(2)],#month
                   int(match.group(1)))          #day
```